# single dimension array in java and trying to get how many numbers in array are bigger than arithmetic mean

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner ulaz=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter number of array elements: ");
   int n=ulaz.nextInt();
   int[]array=new int[n];
   System.out.println("Insert array elements: ");
   int sum=0;
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
       array[i]=ulaz.nextInt();
       sum+=array[i];
   }
   int arithmeticmean=sum/n;
   for(int i=0;i>arithmeticmean;i++){
     System.out.print(i);
   }
}
```

My question is: why can't I see how many elements are bigger than arithmetic mean of this array? What did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: for second loop instead of `arithmeticmean` use the `array.size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing

```
for(int i=0;i>arithmeticmean;i++)
```

Instead of comparing `i` against `arithmeticmean`, compare `array[i]`:

```
for(int i=0;i< array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > arithmeticmean) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

If you want to know how many numbers fulfill this request, then you need to use a counter:

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0;i< array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > arithmeticmean) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println("Amount of items that are greater than arithmetic mean: " + counter);
```

Comment: Thanks, now i realised where i was wrong.It was completely wrong way of thinking how to get wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

To print the values that are bigger than the arithmetic mean you need to loop over all the values and print only the values that are bigger then the arithmetic mean.

```
// Loop through all values
for (int i = 0;i < array.length; i++) {

    // Check if the value is bigger than the arithmetic mean
    if (array[i] > arithmeticmean) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thansk to you to Davide,both of you were helpfull.hope that soon enough i will be as helpfull as you are in Java.